# LibXp.so.6 missing 15.10

Tags: printing, 15.10

Im trying to install a [canon printer driver](http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0045505.asp) on 15.10. I know this worked on an older distribution, but now the installation fails:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i o1512een_linux_CQueDEB_v2010_64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package cque-en.
(Reading database ... 255576 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack o1512een_linux_CQueDEB_v2010_64.deb ...
Unpacking cque-en (2.0-10) ...
Setting up cque-en (2.0-10) ...
Running CQue setup from /opt/cel
/opt/cel/bin/setup: error while loading shared libraries: libXp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Was libXp.so.6 removed recently? Is there a way to make this install?

Edit: It's not available in the [official package sources](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=libxp) anymore

Comment: Why does this have a downvote? I understand it may not be the *best* question ever asked but ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might not be a perfect or ideal solution, but if you download the .deb for the previous ubuntu release (15.04), it seems to install just fine on 15.10. A program that depended on it started working immediately after I installed it.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/amd64/libxp6/download

Comment: Also note there is the [i386 version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/i386/libxp6/download) for older programs

Comment: The link on the answer is broken. I've used [this one](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/vivid/main/base/libxp6).

Comment: That second link is also broken.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu Wily has no package named "libXp".  Only solution I have found is to install the one from the previous version (download the deb file, install manually).  I can't find any justification for this droppage, appears just a goof.

There's a bug report against Ubuntu Wily about it, but no response.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libxp/+bug/1517884

libxp.so is REQUIRED for SAS, a commercial statistics program.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zeehio/libxp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libxp6
```

Caution: it requires adding a PPA, so think twice b4.
To remove the PPA run

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:zeehio/libxp
```

[Source1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libxp/+bug/1517884), [Source2](https://launchpad.net/~zeehio/+archive/ubuntu/libxp)

Comment: This repo is now getting a 404 error

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) the following works.

Add the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main
```

and run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libxp6:i386
```

The `:i386` suffix is only necessary if you need the 32 bit version.

You may also remove the source line from `/etc/apt/sources.list` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install `libxp6`:

```
cd /tmp/
wget -q http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxp/libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get `libxp` being 64 bit errors, or can't find `libXp`, try installing `libxi6:i386`

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to search how many package in Ubuntu related to libXm and motif.

```
sudo apt-get install libmotif*
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libXm*
```

You could see the list of all available lib package.

Comment: How will this help? How are those packages related?

Answer (score -1):

The output posted indicates what the problem is:

```
libXp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This tells you that you do not have such library installed in your system.

The solution to your problem is to install the missing library as follow:

```
 sudo apt-get install libXp
```

After installing the missing library you can install your driver.

Comment: `Unable to locate package libXp`